# Why the filter method does not return the number 0

Tags: javascript, array-filter

When I use filter, the number 0 is not included in the new array:

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
   return a.filter(value => {
       if(!b.includes(value)){
        return value;
      }; 
   });
}

array_diff([1, 2, 0, 4, 2, 6, 4, 1, 4, 0] ,[2,5]);
```

The returned value is: `[1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 4]`. See how 0 is missing.

I also tried to return only the number 0, but the empty array was returned.

How can I fix the `.filter` to include 0 in the result successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0` is falsey, so when you `return value`, if `value` is falsey, it won't be included in the resulting array. Return `true` instead - or, even easier, just return `!b.includes(value)`:

```js
function array_diff(a, b) {
   return a.filter(value => !b.includes(value));
}

console.log(array_diff([1, 2, 0, 4, 2, 6, 4, 1, 4, 0] ,[2,5]));
```

(also note that you need to use the same function name when declaring the function and invoking it - either use `array_diff` for both, or `arrayDiff` for both)

You can reduce the computational complexity of the algorithm from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)` by using a Set instead, if you want. `Set.has` is `O(1)`, whereas `Array.includes` is `O(n)`:

```js
function array_diff(a, b) {
  const set = new Set(b);
  return a.filter(value => !set.has(value));
}

console.log(array_diff([1, 2, 0, 4, 2, 6, 4, 1, 4, 0] ,[2,5]));
```